# Is there a general name for the following graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I would like to know if the following graph has a general name.

The graph is obtained as follows. The inner vertices form a complete graph $K_n$ and attached to each of its outer edges is some cycle.

For example, when $n \geq 3$ and $p,q,r = 3$, $G$ is a complete $n$-sun.

[[image: <span class=]$n, p, q, r \geq 3$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSdqx.jpg)

[image]